# Out of date files must be resolved or reverted. But I have no unresolved files

Tags: submit, perforce, conflict, resolve, p4v

So I resolved all files. No shown/known conflicts reported but I still can't submit.
Also looks like its trying to do a 223 revision but I see no 222 revision in history only 221.

What do I need to do to submit?
using P4V Client app.

Answer (score 2):

Turn on extra log pane options (2 tick boxes) In Edit -> Preferences -> Logging to see the offending files listed in the Log on submit, revert those files and you should be right.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the full error message.  It should be in P4V's log pane, but if you can't find it, go to the command line and retry the submit.  The individual file that has a problem should be listed.

In some edge cases, there may be a file that is out of date but can't be resolved, so it must be reverted; if this is the case, the error mesage for that particular file will say so, and will explain why.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I had one file which was being picked up as new but already existed in repo. I narrowed down to the file by submitting files in chucks/one by one until I hit the file that was causing the error.

So I could submit all but one file and to fix the issue file I reverted the file and made sure it deleted it when I reverted (Note you may not want this and may not have to do that, revert may be fine).